# How run a daemon of djcelery with celerycam

Tags: django, django-celery, djcelery

I'm working with django celery,I have a deamon of celery with supervisor but I have a problem in the django admin I can't see the state of the task,
I can only see  the state of my tasks in the django admin, when I typed in console python manage.py celerycam,
How I run a daemon of celerycam.

Comment: It's the same way you setup celery with supervisor, but with the command `./manage.py celerycam`.

Comment: I have this in  command=/deploy/venvs/venvSite/bin/python deploy/sites/web/manage.py celerycam  , but this is no fine  I have a mistake when run supervisor

Answer (score 0):

You can start your celerycam daemon with your app and celery all together with [supervisorctl](http://supervisord.org/).

Example config file (/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app_name.conf):

```
# app config
[program:app_name]
user = www-data
directory = /var/www/app_name
command = /var/www/app_name/bin/python /var/www/app_name/bin/gunicorn agora.wsgi_server:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8022 -t 90 --workers 4 --settings='app_name.settings.production'
redirect_stderr = true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name_err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=warn
autostart = true
stopsignal=KILL
environment=LANG="en_US.UTF-8",LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8",LC_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

# celerycam config
[program:app_name_celerycam]
user = www-data
directory = /var/www/app_name
command = /var/www/app_name/bin/python manage.py celerycam --settings='app_name.settings.production'
redirect_stderr = true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name_celerycam.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name_celerycam_err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=warn
autostart = true
stopwaitsecs=5

# celery config
[program:app_name_celery]
user = www-data
directory = /var/www/app_name
command = /var/www/app_name/bin/python manage.py celeryd -l INFO -E -B  --settings='app_name.settings.production' --concurrency=1 --pidfile=/var/run/celery/app_name_celery.pid
redirect_stderr = true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name_celery.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/app_name_celery_err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=warn
autostart=true
stopwaitsecs=5
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT=1
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

# group of our daemons
[group:app_name]
programs=app_name,app_name_celerycam,app_name_celery
priority=999
```

Reload our configuration:

```
supervisorctl reread
```

Now we can manage all daemons of our application with simple commands:

```
supervisorctl start app_name:*
supervisorctl stop app_name:*
supervisorctl restart app_name:*
supervisorctl status app_name:*
```